# Next.js router locale issue

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, next-router

I have set up some locales for our app which are `uk` and `us`. For the blog we can have either `us/blog` or just `/blog` for the `uk` locale.

When I switch to `us` like so: (locale = "us")

```
const handleRoute = (locale) => router.push(`${locale}${router.asPath}`)
```

the url gets correctly updated to have `us/` prepended.

When I switch back to `uk` using `handleRoute` (locale= ""), it stays on `us`, although `router.asPath`is equal to `/blog`

Full component:

```
export const CountrySelector: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState<string>(router.locale)

  const handleOnChange = (countryValue) => {
    setSelectedValue(countryValue)
  }

  const handleRoute = (locale) => router.push(`${locale}${router.asPath}`)

  const selectedValueLoweredCase = selectedValue.toLowerCase()

  const getCountryImageUrl = (countryLabel: string): string =>
    `/images/flag-${countryLabel}-sm.png`

  const getImageComponent = (countryLabel: string) => (
    <Image
      htmlWidth="25px"
      src={getCountryImageUrl(countryLabel)}
      alt={selectedValueLoweredCase}
    />
  )

  return (
    <>
      <div data-testid="country-selector">
        {console.log(router)}
        <Menu>
          <MenuButton
            as={Button}
            variant="countrySelector"
            rightIcon={<TriangleDownIcon marginTop="-6px" />}
          >
            <Flex align="baseline">
              <Box
                marginRight="12px"
                display={selectedValueLoweredCase === "us" ? "none" : "block"}
              >
                {getImageComponent("uk")}
              </Box>

              <Box
                marginRight="12px"
                display={selectedValueLoweredCase === "uk" ? "none" : "block"}
              >
                {getImageComponent("us")}
              </Box>
              <Box color={colors.black["100"]}>{selectedValue}</Box>
            </Flex>
          </MenuButton>
          <MenuList padding="0" borderRadius="0">
            <MenuOptionGroup
              onChange={(countryValue) => handleOnChange(countryValue)}
              defaultValue={selectedValue}
              type="radio"
            >
              <MenuItemOption value="UK" color="#000">
                <Flex align="baseline">
                  <Box marginRight="10px">{getImageComponent("uk")}</Box>
                  <Box
                    onClick={() => handleRoute("")}
                    textTransform="uppercase"
                    color={colors.black["100"]}
                  >
                    united kingdom
                  </Box>
                </Flex>
              </MenuItemOption>
              <MenuItemOption value="US">
                <Flex align="baseline">
                  <Box marginRight="10px">{getImageComponent("us")}</Box>
                  <Box
                    onClick={() => handleRoute("us")}
                    textTransform="uppercase"
                    color={colors.black["100"]}
                  >
                    united states
                  </Box>
                </Flex>
              </MenuItemOption>
            </MenuOptionGroup>
          </MenuList>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

nextConfig.js:

```
...
  i18n: {
    localeDetection: false,
    locales: getRegions(), // ["uk", "us"]
    defaultLocale: getDefaultRegion(), // "uk"
  },
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When routing using localized routes, you need to specify the locale by including additional options in the `router.push` call.

In your specific case, you can either do it by passing the desired locale in the options, and omitting it from the path:

```js
const handleRoute = (locale) => router.push(router.asPath, router.asPath, { locale: locale })
```

Or specify it in the path directly but setting `locale` to `false`:

```js
const handleRoute = (locale) => router.push(`${locale}${router.asPath}`, `${locale}${router.asPath}`, { locale: false })
```

Note that in both cases you'll need to pass the extra second param `as` so that the options object can be passed too.

Comment: Thank you very much.